# Differentiating a Vector and a Matrix w.r.t. a Vector [Matrix Calculus]

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, matrix-calculus

I am studying matrix calculus for linear regression and machine learning and I would like to know exactly if the following calculations are correct:

Let $y=\sin(x+yz)$ and $r=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$

Then the following is the gradient of $y$ i.e., the derivative of $y$ with respect the vector $r$ in *denominator* layout: $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial\sin(x+yz)}{\partial r}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial \sin(x+yz)}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial\sin(x+yz)}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial \sin(x+yz}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \cos(x+yz)\\z\cos(x+yz)\\y\cos(x+yz)\end{bmatrix}$$

In numerator layout it would be:

$$[\cos(x+yz), z\cos(x+yz), y\cos(x+yz)]$$

---

Now, let $$\mathbf{y}=\begin{bmatrix} e^{xyz}\\x^2z\\yx\end{bmatrix}$$

So in *numerator* layout: $$\frac{\partial\mathbf{y}}{\partial r}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial e^{xyz}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial e^{xyz}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial e^{xyz}}{\partial z}\\ \frac{\partial x^2z}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial x^2z}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial x^2z}{\partial z}\\ \frac{\partial yx}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial yx}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial yx}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}\\ =\begin{bmatrix} yze^{xyz} & xze^{xyz} & xye^{xyz}\\2xz& 0 & x^2 \\y & x & 0\end{bmatrix} $$

In *denominator* layout it would be the transpose of the above matrix?

---

Now, let

$$Y=\begin{bmatrix} x^2yz & xy^2z \\xyz^2 & \ln(xyz) \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} Y_{11} & Y_{12} \\Y_{21} & Y_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$

Then $$\frac{\partial Y}{\partial r}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial Y_{11}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial Y_{12}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial Y_{11}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial Y_{12}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial Y_{11}}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial Y_{12}}{\partial z} \\ \frac{\partial Y_{21}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial Y_{22}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial Y_{21}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial Y_{22}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial Y_{21}}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial Y_{22}}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}$$

Would this be correct? I'm worrying I mixed up the shape and/or the positions of the members of the matrices $\frac{\partial\mathbf{y}}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial r}$.

Comment: the derivative of a matrix (that is, a 2d-tensor) wrt a vector is a 3d-tensor. In order to avoid that and continue to work with matrices, use the $\mathrm{vec}$ operation on $Y$ to transform it to a vector. The derivative is then a 4x3 (or 3x4, depending on what layout you choose) matrix.

Comment: @lmaosome could you write this as an answer to my question as well as answer my queries? That would be awesome

Comment: @lmaosome In this video (towards 6:30): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrH-jpJIqFQ , he says that it's a kronecker product between $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{ \partial }{\partial z}\right)$ and $Y$

Comment: that corresponds to my vec operation suggestion; I'll write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comments, the derivative of a matrix $Y$ (as a function of a vector $r$) wrt $r$ is a 3d-tensor (c.f. [Derivative of a Matrix with respect to a vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822068/derivative-of-a-matrix-with-respect-to-a-vector)). Since 3d-tensors are difficult to work with, it is convenient to use vectorization. The vectorization operator $\mathrm{vec}$ is the natural isomorphism between $\mathbb R^{n\times k}$ and $\mathbb R^{nk}$. That is, $\mathrm{vec}$ transforms a $n\times k$ matrix to $(nk)\times 1$ vector by stacking the columns of the matrix. Thus, if we are interested in the derivative of $Y$ wrt $r$, we would consider the derivative of $\mathrm{vec}(Y)$ wrt $r'$. The derivative is matrix. Thus, for the derivative of
$$\mathrm{vec}(Y) = \begin{pmatrix} Y_{11} \\ Y_{21}\\ Y_{12} \\ Y_{22} \end{pmatrix}
$$
wrt $$r = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix},$$
we obtain
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r'}\mathrm{vec}(Y) = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}Y_{11} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}Y_{11} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}Y_{11} \\ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}Y_{21} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}Y_{21} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}Y_{21} \\ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}Y_{12} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}Y_{12} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}Y_{12} \\ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}Y_{22} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}Y_{22} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}Y_{22} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Now this results looks slightly different than your expression. Heuristically, this is because in the video the 3d-tensor is "vectorized" (actually, the third dimension is essentially stacked resulting in a 2d-tensor, i.e. a matrix) *after* taking the derivative. In my answer -- and I believe this is the easier and more commonly used way -- the vectorization is done *before* taking the derivative. Eventually, the difference boilds down to the dimension of the derivative and where are the individual partial derivatives are located. Both answers are correct in a sense that both results are isomorph (to make this explicit: apply the $\mathrm{vec}$ operator to your and my result). It is only important to be aware what approach was chosen and to stick with it in order to avoid confusion.